# Stuck on Boolean Array Java Assignment

Tags: java, arrays, boolean

**I have a Java Assignment I'm really struggling on. This is the notes my instructor gave me:**

Write a program that mimics a mailman conducting an experiment in `"flipping mailboxes"`. A flip means opening a mailbox if it is closed, and closing a mailbox if it is open. There are 100 mailboxes numbered 1 to 100 that are all initially closed.

In the first step, visiting every mailbox (i.e. mailboxes 1, 2, 3, 4, etc. until he gets to 100), he flips them all.
In the second step, visiting every second mailbox (i.e. mailboxes 2, 4, 6, 8, etc. until he gets to 100), he flips them.
In the third step, visiting every third mailbox (i.e. mailboxes 3, 6, 9, 12, etc. until he gets to 99), he flips them.
He continues in this manner with steps 4, 5, 6, etc. until he finally reaches 100, wherein he directly goes to the 100th mailbox and flips it.
At the end of this process, which mailboxes are open?
Create a Java Program that will mimic the said experiment. Once you are done, you are to enumerate all the opened mailboxes.

Hint: Set up an array of booleans all initialized to false, representing closed mailboxes. Then, in steps of 1, 2, 3, ... to 100, go through the sequence of mailboxes and toggle them. In the end, print out the mailbox numbers that are open (have the value true).

```
import java.util.Arrays;

    
    public class MailManProblem{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    
boolean[] Mail = new boolean [100];
Arrays.fill(Mail, false);

for(int M = 0; M < Mail.length; M++)
{

Mail[M]= false ;
}
for(int count = 0; count <= Mail.length; count = count++) 
{
Mail[count] = true;
}
for(int count2 = 2; count2<=100; count2++) {
    
    for(int count3 = 2; count3 <= 100; count3 = count3 + 3) {
        
        if(Mail[count3] = false) {
        Mail[count3] = true;} 
        else{ Mail[count3] = false;} 
    }
}       
for(int print =0; Mail.length>=print; print++)
    if(Mail[print] = false)
    {
        System.out.println("Mailbox" + print++ + "is closed" );
    }   

    }
        }
```

This is my work, unfortunately, I can't get it to run, it has no errors though, just no output.

Comment: You need to use double equal signs when testing a boolean variable. Using only 1 equal sign will actually set the variable to false as you are doing in your code here. Therefore your if statement will never be true and thus you get no output.

Comment: Could you expand on that? I not sure when to put double = and when I do, it creates an error.

Comment: Any time you need to use an 'if(condition)' block, you need to use the ==. The double equals is the comparison operator. The single equals sign is the assignment operator. In your code you posted above, if(Mail[print] = false)  is actually setting Mail[print] to false. You're assigning it not comparing it.

Comment: Ok, I changed that and received no errors, but I still don't have an output. I'll have to ask my teacher. :P

Comment: `count = count++` never changes count, just write `count++`. Add outputs in your loops to see what really happens, or use a debugger

Answer (score 1):

It seems like there are several inconsistencies with your code and parts that can be improved.

For instance, when you initialize a boolean array all values are `false` by default so no need to fill the array.

I also think there are some issues with your for loops that will lead to `IndexOutOfBoundException`s. Since you start your indexing on 0 and end with `count <= Mail.length` which will end on index `100` which does not exist. Last index will be `99`.

It is also true about what @Jake Henry said about the comparisons, you need the `==` to do comparisons.

A neat trick when flipping booleans is to negate the current value and then assign that. Example:

```java
Mail[count] = !Mail[count];
```

I think that you also need to take a look at the logic since it seems like you aren't following the instructions fully.

Seeing as this is an assignment, I don't want to give away too much, but a hint here could be to have a for loop that ticks up the amount of steps you need to take in your inner for loop.

I hope this helps.

Comment: I'm really new to Java so quite confused, but thanks anyways.